# How to pass integer value to Controller from httppost method in angular 4?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

In our Angular4 MVC application, we are using http services to get data from Data Layer.
Please see the code snippet

```
this.http.post(_this.baseUrl + "api/User/" + user.UserId)
```

In API controller I am not getting the UserId value.

If I am passing a string value then no issues.

Any one please help to fix the issue.

Comment: Will you please post whole controller and also the service ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the URL that you are using, to make post call all u have to do is create controller action as below:-

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromRoute]int userId)
{
    var id = userId;
    return Ok();
}
```

If user id is string then

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromRoute]string userId)
{
    var id = userId;
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Here I am getting userId as 0. any suggestions?

Comment: what is the value of user id? is it int or string? if it is int it should work if it is string then change the int type to string. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
this.http.post(_this.baseUrl + "api/User/MethodName?userId=1");
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public string MethodName(long userId)
{
     //do you operation
}
```

Please check the url is correct by installing a [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or similar client

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, you got something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/deleteFile/{userId}/{fileName}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean deleteFile(@PathParam("userId") Integer userId, @PathParam("fileName") String fileName);
```

Then the Service function should look like this:

```
public deleteFile( userId: number, fileName: string ): Observable<boolean> {
    const headers = new Headers( { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } );
    /* The option withCredentials: true is used for the CORS variant, that is, when our REST server is on a different WEB server than our node.js server, where my Angular2 development application is.
     */
    const options = new RequestOptions( { headers: headers, withCredentials: true } );

    return this.http.post( this.url + '/deleteFile/' + userId + '/' + fileName, null, options )
        .map( this.extractData )
        .catch( this.handleError );
}
```

This is a simple example of my code that I used for my application not too late ago, it should work.